# Writing á or í in matlab plot title

Tags: matlab, gnuplot, matlab-figure, tex

I run matlab 2008 on Ubuntu 15.10. I need to put some czech words including "á", "í" and so on. Console `disp` is not a problem (but who cares for inline czech statements `Píšeš háčky a čárky, obludo?`). The issue is titles, legends etc. in figures. Naturally, the direct input from the keyboard doesn't work. Here is what I have tried based on docs and google:

- **Try to switch the font, it works fine for some of them.** I haven't been successful so far and I have tried many. Is there any recommended one?
- **TeX that.** It is a nice choice for a caron (háček) (e.g. `\v{s}`), but there is a problem with an accent (čárka) cause `\'{a}` would end the matlab string prematurely.

If the gnuplot would be a better choice, I wouldn't mind switching the enviroments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to use `\''{a}` and to be sure that the interpreter is set to latex (not tex). Example:

```
title('Maxim\''{a}ln\''{i}','FontSize',30,'Interpreter','latex')
```